# What is the proper way to use read discord message history after yesterday?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am using `discordpy` to write a Discord bot using Python. My goal is to iterate through all the messages sent on the current day. The [API reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#textchannel) has gotten me as far as

```py
today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

async for message in message.channel.history(after=???):
```

The API reference says `Optional[Union[Snowflake, datetime.datetime]]`, but I don't quite understand what that means.

What do I need to replace the "???" with in order to iterate through all messages sent on the current day?

Comment: That’s the type of the parameter. Don’t the docs describe what the parameter should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says and links, you need to use a [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object, not a [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object. The equivalent to what you're doing now would be to set `today` to [`datetime.datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now), and then setting `after` to `yesterday`.

Note, however, that as the documentation says, the `datetime` provided is supposed to represent UTC time, so if your local time is not the same as UTC, the time you're specifying will not be interpreted as exactly 24 hours ago. Instead, you should use [`datetime.datetime.utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow).

Also, you're shadowing `message` in the async for loop.

Comment: Thanks! The docs talk about some snowflake object which confused me. I didn't realize it would be this simple!

Comment: No problem. If you click the Snowflake link, it'll direct you to https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Snowflake. It's an ABC for lots of discord.py objects, such as messages, so you could pass a Message object instead as well.